# JSON stringify $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a rudimentary bug-tracker in my web app. I prompt the user for a textual description of the problem, and then I want to attach a JSON representation of $rootScope (values) that I send via $http. Is there a clean way to grab this? `angular.toJson` simply gives me a string that says `$SCOPE`.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Yeah, it is the same - "$SCOPE". I eventually managed to get it working by using _.pick($rootScope, "foo", "bar"). The properties I picked were all of the possible properties I could have from any of my controllers. It's not great, but it is only for rudimentary bug-tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-Logging-Client-Side-Errors-With-AngularJS-And-Stacktrace-js.htm

When used in conjunction with the built-in logging (do a search for $scope.$log) you should have everything you need.